# Using second person in cover letter for a publication

Tags: writing-style, application-cover-letter

I'm writing a cover letter for a study discussing a particular cognitive phenomenon. I'd like to begin with directly inviting the editor to consider this phenomenon in his own daily experience.

My adviser believes that this is an unacceptable deviation from academic style.

Fresh writing or faux pas?

Comment: Certainly not conventional, and might easily alienate some editors. The unconventionality would likely be viewed as unprofessional... what do you imagine to gain by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to sell the paper to the editor.  Write the letter, asking that the paper be considered for publication, and telling the editor anything else he or she needs to know to get the paper to appropriate referees.  Anything else would be odd.